# Sibling Component Comunication in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I saw many tutorials solving this particular problem using a service injected in 2 components and observable to subscribe to changes of some data in the service.

In my project I need this, but I get the same "effect" without observables. If in the service there is an object called `data`, it is passed by reference to the components and therefore the changes are propagated both directions. Angular takes care natively of the bidirectional binding to the templates.

I made the simplest working example here https://embed.plnkr.co/334zd3KkTzPOkNhNfSuS/

It looks to me Observables add unnecessary complexity, but I have mixed feelings about this. Please advise me if I am missing something here. We are using this method in production.

Comment: For _direct_ siblings, you're correct. An observable isn't needed. In the case where your components aren't directly rendered by the parent, or there's multiple levels, etc etc it becomes easier/necessary to use an Observable in a service though.

Comment: One problem of that approach is when you change the change detection strategy of the nested components, see https://plnkr.co/edit/8D0SHWI6UkP9mA9w8ULq?p=preview

Comment: That's all fine and well, but what if a component needs to change its state every time another component changes the object? What if it needs to send a http request every time the value changes? Your way allows sharing state between components, but the component has no way to know when this state has been modified. that's where observables are useful.

Comment: At the benning of using angular 2+ i thought something similar: that observables are not so important. After some time I found out that they are the best for holding and sharing state between different components (even better when they don't have parent-child or sibling relationship)

Comment: Thx for your input. Observables are powerful, but I would not use them when not needed (Using the same design pattern to share the state between components it's not a reason enough I think). My initial doubt is whether the method I mention is reliable or is there something worry about?